# Create a random list of values with corresponding tokens

Tags: python, performance, random, iteration

I have this code that uses loops and random generators to create a random list of values (operators, strings, integers, floats, and new lines) and a corresponding list of the correct tokens to test a lexer I have made. Currently it is estimated to take 1:50 (1 hour 50 mins) to create 1 billion tokens, but I am wondering if it can be faster. I attempted to optimize it by using numpy random functions, but that resulted in a time estimate of 32 hours. Is it possible to improve performance? Here is my code (using `tqdm` for a progress bar and time estimate):

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
import random
import string

nOp = {
'+': 'add',
'-': 'subtract',
'*': 'multiply',
'/': 'divide',
'^': 'exponent',
'/^': 'root',
'%': 'modulo',
'==': 'equal',
'!': 'not', '>':
'greater', '<':
'less', '>=':
'greater_equal',
'<=': 'less_equal',
'&': 'and',
'|': 'or',
'%/': 'divisible'
}

strTuple = tuple((string.ascii_letters + (" " * 8) + "\"" + "'").split())
digitTuple = tuple(string.digits)

s = []
correct = []
for i in tqdm(range(1000000000)):
    #get a random number to determine the data type
    tn = random.randint(0, 16)
    #operator (random from dict above)
    if tn >= 0 and tn <= 3:
        op = random.choice(tuple(nOp.keys()))
        s.append(op.strip().replace("\\", "").replace("(?<= )", "").replace("(?= )", ""))
        correct.append(nOp[op])
    #string (random length and characters)
    elif tn >= 4 and tn <= 7:
        s.append('"' + "".join([random.choice(strTuple) for i in range(random.randint(0, 75))]) + '"')
        correct.append("string")
    #integer (random length and digits)
    elif tn >= 8 and tn <= 11:
        s.append(random.choice(["-", ""]) + "".join([random.choice(digitTuple) for i in range(random.randint(1, 10))]))
        correct.append("integer")
    #float (random length and digits before and after decimal place)
    elif tn >= 12 and tn <= 15:
        s.append(random.choice(["-", ""]) + "".join([random.choice(digitTuple) for i in range(random.randint(1, 10))]) + "." + "".join([random.choice(digitTuple) for i in range(random.randint(1, 10))]))
        correct.append("float")
    #new line
    elif tn == 16:
        s.append("\n")
        correct.append("EOL")
```

Comment: Will this even fit in memory? What will you do with the tokens once this loop is done?

Answer (score 1):

You generate a random float with this line:

```
s.append(random.choice(["-", ""]) + "".join([random.choice(digitTuple) for i in range(random.randint(1, 10))]) + "." + "".join([random.choice(digitTuple) for i in range(random.randint(1, 10))]))
```

There is a function for what you're trying to do:

```
s.append(str(random.uniform(-10**10, 10**10)))
```

Same applies to the line where you generate integers.

---

```
s.append(op.strip().replace("\\", "").replace("(?<= )", "").replace("(?= )", ""))
```

It's unclear what you're trying to do here since `op` doesn't contain any question marks. `strip()` is also redundant.

---

Instead of

```
for i in tqdm(range(1000000000)):
    tn = random.randint(0, 16)
    if tn >= 0 and tn <= 3:
        ...
    elif tn >= 4 and tn <= 7:
        ...
    ...
```

you can use [`choices`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html#random.choices) with weights. This allows you to write it a bit cleaner:

```
for data_type in random.choices(
    ('operator', 'string', 'integer', 'float', 'new line'),
    (4, 4, 4, 4, 1),
    k=10
):
    if data_type == 'operator':
        ...
    if data_type == 'string':
        ...
    ...
```

---

You won't actually be able to store that much data in a list because of limited memory. Why do you need so much anyway?

Comment: _"You generate a random float with this line: ... There is a function for what you're trying to do: ..."_  If we assume (boldly, I know) that OP's code is _doing_ what they want, then this probably isn't a good substitution. `1.0` and `1.0000000000` are the same "number", but it appears they're testing a parser of some kind, so it makes sense that they'd want redundant representations like this.

Answer (score 0):

## Formatting:

- Use a linter. Maybe you already are; this isn't bad. But there are a couple things that *are* annoying to read which a linter would have caught.
- What is going on with the formatting of `nOp`?
- Put comments inside `if` bloacks, same way you put them inside functions.

## Design principals:

- Use a `main` method.
- Parameterize key things like the number of items you want to generate and the RNG you want to use.
- Try using generators and streaming. The `itertools` package will help with this. It's easy to get carried away, and rarely actually affects performance, but it's a nice flexible way to think about things.
- When there's an existing tool that allows you to replace several operations with one, it's usually a good idea to use it:

  - Instead of `[prng.choice(xs) for _ in range(n)]`, use `prng.choices(xs, k=n)`.
  - Avoid string concatenation. It's basically fine for these situations, but f-strings are better for more complicated constructions, so just use them for everything.
  - Instead of matching ranges of numbers, just draw the random number from a non-uniform distribution using `choices`.
- Most of the time, an `if/elif` batch should also have an `else` that says what happens if they all fail.
- Especially when there are a lot of strings being used (which is itself often a red flag), declare them as constants (kinda like you do with `digitTuple`).

## Is this actually doing what you want?

- Should there be integer cases that start with a plus sign?
- Is it ok that negative zero will show up in this? Multiple leading zeros?
- What is `op.strip().replace("\\", "").replace("(?<= )", "").replace("(?= )", "")` doing? This probably shouldn't be there.
- `tuple((string.ascii_letters + (" " * 8) + "\"" + "'").split())` yields
  `('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '"\'')`,
  you probably wanted each each character as its own option, right? Possibly including space. Did you mean for spaces to be weighted more heavily? But won't the double-quotes inside the words then be indistinguishable from the ones you're wrapping around the words?
- It looks like you're randomly generating test cases for a parser? There's probably an off-the-shelf tool for that; I know the normal practice is to generate fewer test cases in a less-random way, to make sure you're covering all the interesting *edge* cases instead of wasting time exploring homogeneous planes of randomness.

**The above changes have no effect on the performance that I've been able to discern.**

- Precalculate even more stuff?
- If `nOp` keys don't need further processing, just sample directly from `nOp.items()`?

**But still, no meaningful change...**

I was able to eak out another 30% speed improvement (give-or-take measurement error) by just cutting out tqdm, but I don't know what good that does you.